# How to change value of Material-UI's Textfield on focus?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to change the value of `Material-UI`'s `TextField` when it focuses. It seems that I can do that through `inputProps`, but I can't find any example of how to implement that.

Comment: why don't you just change on focus value ? like make function which supplies prop `value` into text field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add onFocus prop with TextField

`<TextField value={this.state.value} onFocus={onFocus} label="Custom CSS" variant="outlined" id="custom-css-outlined-input" />`

then handle the onFocus event

```
      const onFocus = () => { 
        this.setState({
          value:'new value'
          })
        }
```

it should update the value in the field when focus comes on the text field

Comment: Thanks, this works. It's just odd that they don't have it in their documentation.